# Matsumura, CRT, Exercise 6.3

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The questions states:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $x\in A$ be an element which is neither a unit nor a zero-divisor; prove $\operatorname{Ass}_A(A/xA)=\operatorname{Ass}_A(A/x^nA)$ for each $n=1,2,\ldots.$

My question is to whether $A$ needs to be Noetherian for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the noetherian hypothesis on order Ass be defined. In non-noetherian rings, the useful notion is that of `weakly associated` prime ideals. Cf. N. Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra, Ch. IV, §1, exercise 17.

Comment: I might be missing something, but at least in Matsumura $$\text{Ass}_A M:=\{P\in\text{Spec} A: P=(0:x)_A\text{ for some }x\in M-\{0\}\},$$ is the same definition you are operating under? Also, with this definition in mind, is Noetherian a necessary hypothesis?

Comment: For $\operatorname{Ass}_AM$, yes. The definition of a weakly associated prime ideal is it's a prime ideal that is `minimal` above some $(0:x)_A$.